# Heroku War Deploy SSL Error

Tags: java, ssl, heroku

I am trying to upload war file to Heroku. But I am getting SSL error.

My application is in domain "*.herukoapp.com".

How can this SSL error can be solved?

> -----> Uploading build... Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>           at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
>           at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
>           at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.utils.RestClient.put(RestClient.java:154)
>           at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.endpoints.ApiEndpoint.upload(ApiEndpoint.java:47)
>           at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.BuildsDeployer.deploySlug(BuildsDeployer.java:101)
>           at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.Deployer.createAndReleaseSlug(Deployer.java:121)
>           at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:80)
>           at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.App.deploy(App.java:60)
>           at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.App.deploy(App.java:64)
>           at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.WarApp.deploy(WarApp.java:30)
>           at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeployWar.main(DeployWar.java:109) Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path
>   building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: `sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification`! I guess the certificate is not valid hence the handshake failure.

Comment: Yes correct. But how to make heroku to configure SSL certificate. It is specific to heroku.

Comment: Are you running Java 7 locally? That's most likely the problem as it doesn't support TLS v1.1 and higher. Upgrade to Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by running an old version of Java 7 locally. Heroku disabled TLS v1.0, and your Java doesn't support anything new. You can either:

- Upgrade to [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
- Upgrade to [Zulu JDK 7 (u141 or newer)](http://zulu.org/download/) (Oracle doesn't support JDK 7 anymore)

Comment: No. I use Java 1.8. Updating also did not solve the issue

Comment: What version of Java 8 are you on now? can you show output of `java -version`?

Comment: > java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

Comment: is it possible to SSL certificate of heroku? so that I can add to my java trust store.

Comment: Yea, you can download it with `openssl` from api.heroku.com:443. Then import it into your `cacerts` with `keytool`. Are you installing JDK from apt? I suspect you system certs are out of date.